# List of all subscription

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reporting-services

How to check all report's subscriptions on Sharepoint 2010?

I know only how to check subsciption on specific report:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SSRS API to find all subscriptions created under a given site, as per the documentation of the **ListSubscriptions** method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt213495.aspx#M:ReportService2010.ReportingService2010.ListSubscriptions(System.String)

"**Parameters**

*ItemPathOrSiteURL*

*Type: System.String*

The fully qualified URL of the site or item including the file name and, in SharePoint mode, the extension.
If a report server URL or SharePoint site URL is specified, all subscriptions at the given server or site is returned."

To use the API you'll need to write some custom code, unfortunately - the code in the MSDN article should work in a console app provided that you run it on the SharePoint server.